# How to get an Option's value or set it if it's empty?

Tags: rust

I want to get the `name` if it's not empty or set a new value. How can I do that?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct App {
    name: Option<String>,
    age: i32,
}

impl App {
    fn get_name<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a Option<String> {
        match self.name {
            Some(_) => &self.name,
            None => {
                self.name = Some(String::from("234"));
                &self.name
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut app = App {
        name: None,
        age: 10,
    };

    println!("{:?} and name is {}", &app, &app.get_name().unwrap())
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:25:44
   |
25 |     println!("{:?} and name is {}", &app, &app.get_name().unwrap())
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `app` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:25:44
   |
25 |     println!("{:?} and name is {}", &app, &app.get_name().unwrap())
   |     ---------------------------------------^^^---------------------
   |     |                                |     |
   |     |                                |     mutable borrow occurs here
   |     |                                immutable borrow occurs here
   |     immutable borrow ends here
   |
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks to me like you want the [`get_or_insert_with()` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.22.0/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.get_or_insert_with). This executes a closure when the `Option` is `None` and uses the result as the new value:

```
fn get_name(&mut self) -> &String {
    self.name.get_or_insert_with(|| String::from("234"))
}
```

If you already have a value to insert, or creating the value isn't expensive, you can also use the [`get_or_insert()` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.22.0/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.get_or_insert):

```
fn get_name(&mut self) -> &String {
    self.name.get_or_insert(String::from("234"))
}
```

---

You'll also need to change your `main()` function to avoid the borrowing issue. An easy solution would be to derive `Clone` on your struct and then `.clone()` it in the call to `println!()`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut app = App {
        name: None,
        age: 10,
    };

    println!("{:?} and name is {}", app.clone(), app.get_name())
}
```

Comment: Within a function that returns `Result`, is there an idiomatic way to return an error from inside `get_or_insert_with` (like what the `?` normally does) but let an `Ok` be unwrapped and stuffed inside the `Option`? The closure "catches" the error and doesn't let it bubble up, which is annoying.